# Как заблокировать возможность переворота экрана до окончания загрузки

Tags: java, android

Собственно вопрос в заголовке. У меня имеется `AsyncTask` задача, где по завершению загрузки `progressBar` сетается на `setVisibility(View.GONE);`, я думаю, что задачу можно решить поместив `boolean` после `progressBar`'а и делать ее `true`, и если она `true` разрешать поворот. Но я не знаю как мне до этого момента блокировать возможность переворота экрана, придумал такой костыль и поместил в `onCreate`, в `onPause` тоже пробовал.

Answer (score 2):

Для блокирования поворота установи флаг:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);
```

Comment: А где вызывать метод тогда?

Comment: Тогда, когда вам нужно заблокировать возможность поворота. Т.е. до начала асинхронной операции. А вообще, я бы не рекомендовал такое решение. Это костыль. Лучше разберитесь как работать с AsyncTaskLoader. Он как раз для решения вашей задачи.